# tensorflow record with float numpy array

Tags: numpy, tensorflow

I want to create tensorflow records to feed my model;
so far I use the following code to store uint8 numpy array to TFRecord format;

```
def _int64_feature(value):
  return tf.train.Feature(int64_list=tf.train.Int64List(value=[value]))


def _bytes_feature(value):
  return tf.train.Feature(bytes_list=tf.train.BytesList(value=[value]))


def _floats_feature(value):
  return tf.train.Feature(float_list=tf.train.FloatList(value=[value]))


def convert_to_record(name, image, label, map):
    filename = os.path.join(params.TRAINING_RECORDS_DATA_DIR, name + '.' + params.DATA_EXT)

    writer = tf.python_io.TFRecordWriter(filename)

    image_raw = image.tostring()
    map_raw   = map.tostring()
    label_raw = label.tostring()

    example = tf.train.Example(features=tf.train.Features(feature={
        'image_raw': _bytes_feature(image_raw),
        'map_raw': _bytes_feature(map_raw),
        'label_raw': _bytes_feature(label_raw)
    }))        
    writer.write(example.SerializeToString())
    writer.close()
```

which I read with this example code

```
features = tf.parse_single_example(example, features={
  'image_raw': tf.FixedLenFeature([], tf.string),
  'map_raw': tf.FixedLenFeature([], tf.string),
  'label_raw': tf.FixedLenFeature([], tf.string),
})

image = tf.decode_raw(features['image_raw'], tf.uint8)
image.set_shape(params.IMAGE_HEIGHT*params.IMAGE_WIDTH*3)
image = tf.reshape(image_, (params.IMAGE_HEIGHT,params.IMAGE_WIDTH,3))

map = tf.decode_raw(features['map_raw'], tf.uint8)
map.set_shape(params.MAP_HEIGHT*params.MAP_WIDTH*params.MAP_DEPTH)
map = tf.reshape(map, (params.MAP_HEIGHT,params.MAP_WIDTH,params.MAP_DEPTH))

label = tf.decode_raw(features['label_raw'], tf.uint8)
label.set_shape(params.NUM_CLASSES)
```

and that's working fine. Now I want to do the same with my array "map" being a float numpy array, instead of uint8, and I could not find examples on how to do it;
I tried the function _floats_feature, which works if I pass a scalar to it, but not with arrays;
with uint8 the serialization can be done by the method tostring();

How can I serialize a float numpy array and how can I read that back?

Answer (score 16):

`FloatList` and `BytesList` expect an iterable. So you need to pass it a list of floats. Remove the extra brackets in your `_float_feature`, ie

```
def _floats_feature(value):
  return tf.train.Feature(float_list=tf.train.FloatList(value=value))

numpy_arr = np.ones((3,)).astype(np.float)
example = tf.train.Example(features=tf.train.Features(feature={"bytes": _floats_feature(numpy_arr)}))
print(example)

features {
  feature {
    key: "bytes"
    value {
      float_list {
        value: 1.0
        value: 1.0
        value: 1.0
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: How do you handle this for a two-dimensional NumPy array

Answer (score 5):

I will expand on the Yaroslav's answer.

Int64List, BytesList and FloatList expect an [iterator of the underlying elements](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/r1.2/tensorflow/core/example/feature.proto#L65) (repeated field). In your case you can use a list as an iterator.

You mentioned: *it works if I pass a scalar to it, but not with arrays*. And this is expected, because when you pass a scalar, your `_floats_feature` creates an array of one float element in it (exactly as expected). But when you pass an array you create a list of arrays and pass it to a function which expects a list of floats.

So just remove construction of the array from your function: `float_list=tf.train.FloatList(value=value)`

Answer (score 3):

I've stumbled across this while working on a similar problem. Since part of the original question was how to read back the `float32` feature from `tfrecords`, I'll leave this here in case it helps anyone:

If `map.ravel()` was used to input `map` of dimensions `[x, y, z]` into `_floats_feature`:

```py
features = {
    ...
    'map': tf.FixedLenFeature([x, y, z], dtype=tf.float32)
    ...
}
parsed_example = tf.parse_single_example(serialized=serialized, features=features)
map = parsed_example['map']
```

Answer (score 1):

Yaroslav's example failed when a nd array was the input:

numpy_arr = np.ones((3,3)).astype(np.float)

I found that it worked when I used numpy_arr.ravel() as the input. But is there a better way to do it?

Comment: Yaroslav mentioned that you need list of floats, num_arr is not a list so you would have to flatten it somehow and then fix its shape before passing it to the model.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, many thanks to Yaroslav and Salvador for their enlightening answers.

According to my experience, their methods only works when the input is a 1D NumPy array as the size of `(n, )`. When the input is a Numpy array with the dimension of more than 2, the following error info appears:

```
def _float_feature(value):
    return tf.train.Feature(float_list=tf.train.FloatList(value=value))

numpy_arr = np.arange(12).reshape(2, 2, 3).astype(np.float)
example = tf.train.Example(features=tf.train.Features(feature={"bytes": 
_float_feature(numpy_arr)}))
print(example)


TypeError: array([[0., 1., 2.],
   [3., 4., 5.]]) has type numpy.ndarray, but expected one of: int, long, float
```

So, I'd like to expand on Tsuan's answer, that is, flattening the input before it was fed into the TF example. The modified code is as follows:

```
def _floats_feature(value):
    return tf.train.Feature(float_list=tf.train.FloatList(value=value))

numpy_arr = np.arange(12).reshape(2, 2, 3).astype(np.float).flatten()
example = tf.train.Example(features=tf.train.Features(feature={"bytes": 
_float_feature(numpy_arr)}))
print(example)
```

In addition, `np.flatten()` is more applicable than `np.ravel()`.

Answer (score 0):

Use [tfrmaker](https://pypi.org/project/tfrmaker/), a TFRecord utility package. You can install the package with pip:

```
pip install tfrmaker
```

Then you could create tfrecords like this:

```
from tfrmaker import images

# mapping label names with integer encoding.
LABELS = {"bishop": 0, "knight": 1, "pawn": 2, "queen": 3, "rook": 4}

# specifiying data and output directories.
DATA_DIR = "datasets/chess/"
OUTPUT_DIR = "tfrecords/chess/"

# create tfrecords from the images present in the given data directory.
info = images.create(DATA_DIR, LABELS, OUTPUT_DIR)

# info contains a list of information (path: releative path, size: no of images in the tfrecord) about created tfrecords
print(info)
```

The package also has some cool features like:

- dynamic resizing
- splitting tfrecords into optimal shards
- spliting training, validation, testing of tfrecords
- count no of images in tfrecords
- asynchronous tfrecord creation

**NOTE:** This package currently supports image datasets that are organised as directories with class names as sub directory names.